# All closed subsets of the image of $\mathbb C^n$ under rational mapping

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

Let $p_1,\dots,$ $p_{n}$, $q_1,\dots,q_{n}$ be polynomials in the variables $z_1,\dots,z_m$ and
$$
Y:=\{(z_1,\dots,z_m):\ q_1(z_1,\dots,z_m)\ne 0,\dots,  q_{n}(z_1,\dots,z_m)\ne 0\}\subset \mathbb C^m.
$$
We define the set $Z\subset\mathbb C^n$ as the image of $Y$ under the mapping
\begin{equation*} 
%\begin{split}
\phi:\ (z_1,\dots,z_m)\in Y\mapsto\left(\frac{p_1(z_1,\dots,z_m)}{q_1(z_1,\dots,z_m)},\dots,\frac{p_{n}(z_1,\dots,z_m)}{q_{n}(z_1,\dots,z_m)}\right)\in Z,
%\end{split}
\end{equation*}
that is, $Z=\phi(Y)$. We define the varity $V$ as closure of $Z$ (we use the Zariski topology).

It is clear that if $Y_1$ is a closed subset of $Y$, then the closure of $\phi(Y_1)$ is
a closed subset of $V$.

Question: Is it true that every closed subset of $V$ can be obtained in this way?

Comment: What about just taking $\phi^{-1}$ of that closed subset?

Comment: @JohnBrevik I was thinking about this, but $\phi^{-1}$ is defined only on $Z$ (so we cannot take $\phi^{-1}$  for points in $V\setminus Z$). May it happen that some closed subsets of $V$ live in $V\setminus  Z$?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are asking now -- sorry! Indeed, for example with the rational map $\mathbb C^2 -\to \mathbb C^2$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y/x)$, the image is $\mathbb C^2$ minus the entire $y$-axis, which is surely a closed subset and so not recoverable in that form.

Comment: Thanks for this simple counterexample!